# Have an element only show when another element is not on screen

Tags: html, css

EDIT: I think I have confused some solutioners here, I would like to keep the first add to cart while hiding the second sticky one only showing when the first comes off view of the user

I essentially have 2 add to cart buttons, second add to cart only is visible <768px and showing at the bottom of the screen.

How would I make the second add to cart hide while the first add to cart is on the visible on screen

Also can this be done with only css

My code for the second sticky add to cart for reference

```
.sticky-add-to-cart{
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
  .sticky-add-to-cart {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    top: inherit !important;
    z-index: 9999;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: Inside the same media query write css to hide the second button.

Comment: How about making the second sticky and with top set to first's top plus screen's height?

Comment: Or, use only one with fixed position?

Comment: @iAmOren oh that might sound like an option. Only showing the second after the user passes a certain point.

Comment: Clarify, please: scroll right-left or top-bottom or both?

Comment: @iAmOren top-bottom, but it seems below that JS will be the thing I needed (wanted to avoid) which is the action I really wanted - when the user scrolls passed

Comment: @iAmOren do you agree with Wais that this really cant be done with CSS?

Comment: Re: "do you agree with Wais that this really cant be done with CSS?" - I don't know...

Comment: `button { position: sticky; top: 0; left: 0; display: inline-block; }` with containing element also `inline-block`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show the second button when the user scrolls past the first button, then you will need some javascript to do that.

**HTML**

```
<button id="btn1"></button>
<button id="btn2"></button>
```

**CSS**

```
#btn1 {
  display: block;
}

#btn2 {
  display: none;
}

#btn2.show {
  display: block;
}
```

**JS**

```
var scrollAmount;
var btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  scrollAmount = window.scrollY;
  if(scrollAmount > 768px) {
    btn2.classList.add("show");
  } else {
    btn2.classList.remove("show");
  }
});
```

768px is the scroll amount after which the first button disappears from the viewport.

Comment: thanks for the prompt answer, I confused you with my explanation, I would like to keep the first add to cart and only show second while the first is out of view.

Comment: This does exactly what you want. When the width is above 768px, **only** the first button is shown. When the width is below 768px, **only** the second button is shown.

Comment: think im explaining wrong, ok so a user on mobile, sees the first add to cart, when they scrolls passed the first, the second will show

this is what I would like done :D

Comment: As far as I get you, you want only one button to appear at a time. Am I right?

Comment: correct, so currently on <768px they both show, but what I want to happen is they should both show on <768px but only 1 or the other. So while the first is in view of the mobile user, hide the second sticky ATC button until the first is out of view

Comment: I think josh wants a solution with css only = without js.

Comment: It's not possible unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can take an atomic approach to this. Create a couple of helper classes which make the element that they're applied to visible only beyond a certain widths. You can reuse these classes in other components too, if need be.

```
.show-on-desktop{
    display: block;
}
.show-on-phone{
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .show-on-desktop {
    display: none;
  }
  .show-on-phone {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like Wais beat me to it by a minute :D

Comment: Think im confusing people XD, so essentially what I want to happen is when a user on a mobile/tablet, when they scrolls passed the first ATC then second will pop up after the first was scrolled passed. I dont want to completely hide it

Comment: My bad. In that case, you need to use a JS based approach where you can check on scroll when the cart button that you want to hide nears offsetTop and apply the classes.

Comment: There's no way in CSS to trigger onScroll, so I'm afraid not. The JS in this answer might help you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/40821886/2427237

Answer (score -1):

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
}
span {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.button {
  position: sticky;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</span><br>
  <span>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</span><br>
  <span>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</span><br>
  <span>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</span><br>
  <span>blah blah blah <button class="button">Button</button> blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</span><br>
  <span>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</span><br>
  <span>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</span><br>
  <span>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</span><br>
  <span>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</span><br>
  <span>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</span><br>
  <span>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</span><br>
  <span>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</span><br>
  <span>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</span><br>
  <span>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</span><br>
  <span>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</span><br>
  <span>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</span><br>
  <span>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</span><br>
  <span>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</span><br>
  <span>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</span><br>
  <span>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</span><br>
  <span>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</span><br>
  <span>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</span><br>
  <span>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</span><br>
  <span>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</span><br>
  <span>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</span><br>
  <span>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</span><br>
  <span>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</span><br>
  <span>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</span><br>
  <span>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</span><br>
  <span>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</span><br>
  <span>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</span><br>
  <span>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</span><br>
  <span>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</span><br>
  <span>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</span><br>
  <span>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</span><br>
  <span>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</span><br>
  <span>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</span><br>
  <span>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</span><br>
  <span>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</span><br>
  <span>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</span><br>
  <span>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</span><br>
</div>
```